# hide/show of div class

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote a code to show a div element(shareform) when a link is clicked and to hide it when the link is clicked again. I have many Forms under which this link 'Share' will be displayed. If i have only one Form, this code works fine. That is, initially the 'shareform' element is hidden and when I click the link, it is shown and when I click the link again the 'shareform' is hidden.

If I have 2 forms, the 'shareform' element for the second Form is not hidden initially. Isn't this $('#shareform').hide(); suppose to hide the form for all the Share links?

And also, when I click the second "share" link, the 'shareform'  is shown and hidden for the first "share" link. What Am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

```
    var flag=0;
    $('#shareform').hide();
    $(".Share").click(function(){
        if(flag==1){
            $('#shareform').hide('fast');
            flag=0;
        }
        else{
            $('#shareform').show('slow');
        flag=1;
            return false;
        }

     });//.Share click

    $("#shareform .button").click(function(){
        $("#userList option:selected").each(function(){
            selected_value[i]=$(this).val();
            alert(selected_value[i]);
            i++;
        });
    });

   <li id="Share<?php echo $r['Form']['id']?>">
   <a href="#" class="Share">Share</a>
   <form action="/cake_1_2/forms/share/<?=$formid?>/<?=$userid?>" method="post" name="shareform" id="shareform">

   <p>Select the users with whom you want to share the Form</p>
   <select id="userList" name="userList" multiple>
   <?php foreach($users as $user){  ?>
      <option value="<?=$user['User']['name']?>"><?=$user['User']['name'];?></option>

   <?php }?>
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Share"/>
    </form> 
</li>
```

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry, actually i want to hide only the id element share_form,not the class 'Share' coz that class refers to the link alone. also i changed share_form to shareform,it still doesnt work.

EDIT 2:

Ok, I've changed id to class,i.e class='shareform'. Now the shareform class is hidden initially. But if I click the 'Share' link, the 'shareform' class is showed for both the forms.

Comment: One quick suggestion to simplify things a bit.  Why not just set the CSS for shareform to display:none instead of using $('#shareform').hide();

Another suggestion, Have you viewed the source/output of the php page to confirm that you are using the correct IDs?  Toggling the visibility on the shareform id should be very simple and you should be able to select it with $("#shareform")

Comment: I updated my answer below based on your "EDIT 2" update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're assigning different IDs to the different share divs in the different forms?

This line in your question leads me to believe you're not:

> If I have 2 forms, the Share class for
>   the second Form is not hidden
>   initially. Isn't this
>   $('#share_form').hide(); suppose to
>   hide the class for all the Share
>   links?

Also, that line won't hide the class for the share divs since you are only targeting a specific ID with the "#" sign.  To target the share divs with class share you'll want to use $('.Share').hide();

EDIT 2:  Both divs are showing because you are targeting both of them by the class designation.  Instead you want to target them individually by ID.  You'll want to change this line $(".Share").click to $("#Share1").click and then add another function for $("#Share2").click.

Answer (score 2):

For hide/fade interaction I recommend you to use the [Effects/toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) function.

```
$('#share_form').hide();
```

The above line, will hide the element with the id="share_form", the entire form element.

Answer (score 2):

# is actually jQuery shorthand for 'ids'. To hide a class, change the # to ., as in .Share, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that "share_form" is with underscore, sometimes jQuery cannot select a element with underscore, try with "share-form".

Comment: You don't need a signature, especially one to your blog.